# How can I get parent id by onclick on a child in js?

Tags: javascript

```
    <div id="rnd()"><button onclick="checkId()">Click</button></div>
```

I have a DIV when I make by DOM in JS and has a random ID, his child this button.

I need at the click of a button I can know what the ID of the parent (DIV).

Comment: Your question is not clear; could you rephrase it ?

Comment: As all the answers to the purported duplicate use JQuery, this question is still useful. At least here you get some JS-only answers.

Answer (score 26):

You need to update your function call to include `this`:

```
<div id="rnd()"><button onClick="checkId(this)">Click</button></div>

<script>
function checkId(elem)
{
    alert(elem.parentNode.id);
}
</script>
```

or add the event using javascript and give your button an id like this:

```
<div id="rnd()"><button id="myBtn">Click</button></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function(e){
      alert(e.target.parentNode.id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to assign it a class and then just use jQuery to get the id such as this:

```
$('.check-id').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Your div would look like this:

```
<div id="rnd()"><button class="check-id">Click</button></div>
```

With the above approach you can have many buttons and divs and this would work.  You just have to make sure to assign a check-id class to the button.

Answer (score 3):

You should update the function to take in 'this' So like the following:

```
<div id="rnd()"><button onclick="checkId(this)">Click</button></div>
```

Then within the `checkId` function you should have the following:

```
var parentDiv = this.parentNode;
var id = parentDiv.getAttribute("id");
```