# Is there a way to get child's parent name using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

so, I'm literally new to JavaScript, I've been reading and searching about it in here and other places.

This may be super easy, but I'm stuck and I don't know how to get it done.

Here is the deal. I'm trying to get the parent's name through the child id/class/tag.
I'll demonstrate.

```
<li class="example">example</li>
  <ul id="what i want">what i want</ul>
    <li id="something here">something here</li>
      <img class="element i'm using">element im using</img>
```

So, I can get, through `document.getElementById`, the "element i'm using". I want to get the "what i want". I can't really use the same thing because that element has some random numbers that I can't predict.

My plan is to use "element i'm using" to get "what i want" and apply a rule.

I'm a literally beginner, if it's someting basic I'm sorry, but I couldn't find a solution yet.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks, have a good day.

--- Edit/Update ---

Hey, I quick update.

I've found a way to do what I want. I'll explain better, but I'm struggling again.

Here we go:

```html
<li class="bp-body">
 <ul id="random-number-1">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="100-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul class="random-number-2">
  <li id="voice">
   <img class="101-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul id="random-number-3">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="102-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul id="random-number-4">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="100-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

So, my original problem was that I was trying to get the `<ul id="random-number-1">` through the `<img class="100-photo">`. And I've done that. I used a function to return the `document.querySelector("100-photo")` parent, which is `<li class="voice">`, and to get the node I wanted I ran the function with .parent, and it returned the `<ul id="random-number-1">` so I could set a property. It worked fine, but I've found another problem: this solution only returns the first `<ul>` that contains the `<img class="100-photo">` on node tree, but in the reality the `<li class="bp-body">` may have others `<ul id="random-number-xxxx">`.

Here is the function that I used:

```
function findParent() { 
 return document.querySelector("100-photo").parentNode;
}
findParent().parentNode.style.setProperty('background', '#fff');
```

The element `<ul id="random-number-1">` got a nice white background, but the other elements with the same `<img class="100-photo">` stayed the same. I tried to find a workaround.

I tried the querySelectorAll first to find all the elements, I used console.log to see if it works.

```
function getParents() {
 return document.querySelectorAll("100-photo");
}
```

It returned in the console:
`NodeList [ img.100-photo , img.100-photo ]`

Great, that's a start. But when I tried to do the same trick, it didn't work.

```
function getParents() {
 return document.querySelectorAll("100-photo").parentNode;
}
```

The console only shows: `undefined`.

I thought that with a loop it may work with the solution, but I'm not with it familiar yet. I tried to workaround something to at least get a NodeList with `<li class="voice">` which contains the `<img class="100-photo">` but I got nothing yet.

My objective is to identify every `<img class="100-photo">` to get the respective `<li>` parent to get the `<ul id="random-number-xxxx">` to set a property.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: That looks like invalid HTML... A `<li>` should not have `<ul>` as a sibling (and neither should have `<img>` as a sibling)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how i get parent id by onclick Child in js
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213858/how-i-get-parent-id-by-onclick-child-in-js)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah, theres others elements before that. I used this piece to demonstrate what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***:

As per your latest code update, the below should work.

**Replace this code**

> function findParent() {   return
>   document.querySelector("100-photo").parentNode; }
>   findParent().parentNode.style.setProperty('background', '#fff');

**With the below code**

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("100-photo")
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(item) { 
 item.parentNode.parentNode.style.setProperty('background', '#00aae4'); 
});
```

```html
<li class="bp-body">
 <ul id="random-number-1">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="100-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul class="random-number-2">
  <li id="voice">
   <img class="101-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul id="random-number-3">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="102-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul id="random-number-4">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="100-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

==========================================================================

If you know the child elements ID and want to access the parent element, you can use the below:

```
document.getElementById("child_id").parentElement
```

Doc for [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

Example Below:

When you run the code snippet, you will see the parent div printed in the console below.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("child").parentElement
console.log(parent)
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">I m a child of parent div </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to run, and the console returned this: "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null", between the () I put the actual value. I tried to change to "document.getElementsClassName" and got through without errors, but only displayed "undefined" (same with "document.getElementsByTagName").

Comment: Can you create a simple https://jsfiddle.net/ with what you have done so that it is easier to check and advise?

Comment: I updated the first post with more information. @yogZ

Comment: In your latest code sample, you are using querySelectorAll which returs a list/array and hence you need to loop into each one inside it. You can use forEach like below:
document.querySelector("100-photo").forEach(function(item) {
  item.parentNode.parentNode.style.setProperty('background', '#fff');
});

Comment: Hum... Where do I put the code with forEach? I tried to put in the console and it returned `undefined`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working copy as per your latest given code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <div class="child2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The children property returns an array of elements, like so:

```
parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
children = parent.children; // [<div class="child1">]
```

There are alternatives to querySelector, like document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0] if you so desire.

You could just use querySelectorAll to get decendents of parent having a class name of child1:

```
children = document.querySelectorAll('.parent .child1');
```

The difference between qS and qSA is that the latter returns all elements matching the selector, while the former only returns the first such element.

Comment: I see, huh. So, in the grandparent (is this the correct name?) that I want it is formed by a randomize number, I can't really predict what it would be to use in the function/script. I can only use the child, that it's not randomized. The plan is to use this child to get the grandparent id/class so I can set a property.

Comment: Hey, I updated the first post with more information about the problem and such. @user6250770

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

According to your requirement below code will do the job.

```js
function findParent(element) { 
  return element.parentNode;
}

var childrens = document.getElementsByClassName("100-photo");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(childrens, child => {
  findParent(child).parentNode.style.setProperty('background', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<li class="bp-body">
 <ul id="random-number-1">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="100-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul class="random-number-2">
  <li id="voice">
   <img class="101-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul id="random-number-3">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="102-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="white-line"></div>
 <ul id="random-number-4">
  <li class="voice">
   <img class="100-photo">(photo)</img>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

```js
alert(document.getElementById('element_use').closest('#element_want').id);
```

```html
<li class="example">example</li>
    <ul id="element_want">what i want <!-- removed <ul> from here  -->
        <li id="something here"> <!-- removed <li> from here  -->
            Something here
            <img class="element_use" id="element_use">element im using</img>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

You can use **closest** to find out your desired parent element

```
document.getElementById("element_u _use").closest('.parent_u_need_class');
```

**Updated Answer**
I Answered according to your HTML indentation, I've done some changes according to your indentation.

**Closest** function looks for the parents having matching value passed in parameter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get through. Could you elaborate using the example? So I can understand how it would work.

Comment: I tried to run using your answers, putting the actual value, but I kept getting "document.getElementById(...).closest is not a function" on the log.
I tried to change the document.(...) to getElementsByClassName and got the same result.

Comment: May be you have not given any ID to your child element. Can you show me the actual HTML you are using?

Comment: @Mohhamad yasin I updated the first post with more information about it.

Comment: So, I may be doing something wrong of missing something. I copied your code with the updated version, and when I ran it, I got the message `ReferenceError: element is not defined`. I tried to change things around to see what happens, but it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Firstly make sure you have more than 0 childrens in your children variable. Secondly you should pass child variable as findParent(child) function parameter. It should work if you have copied both HTML and JS code as well