# Javascript - Retrieving values of a div when a button inside that div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm writing the code to edit a database table.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="1">
<div contenteditable>aaa</div>
<div contenteditable>bbb</div>
<div contenteditable>ccc</div>

<button onClick="a('save')">SAVE</button>
<button onClick="a('delete')">DELETE</button>
</div>

<div id="2">
<div contenteditable>ddd</div>
<div contenteditable>eee</div>
<div contenteditable>fff</div>

<button onClick="a('save')">SAVE</button>
<button onClick="a('delete')">DELETE</button>
</div>

<div id="3">
<div contenteditable>ggg</div>
<div contenteditable>hhh</div>
<div contenteditable>iii</div>

<button onClick="a('save')">SAVE</button>
<button onClick="a('delete')">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

And so on.

Using the following function, I can get the clicked button:

```
function a(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

When a button (SAVE or DELETE) is clicked, I need to retrieve:

- the id of the "parent" div;
- the content of each of the three contenteditable divs inside the same "parent" div.

Is it possible using pure Javascript?

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is implement click listeners in JS, that way I can query elements easily.

Here is the example:

```js
// Query all div.div-editable elements
document.querySelectorAll('div.div-editable')
  .forEach((div) => {
    // The id of the parent
    const divId = div.id;

    // Each of content editable divs inside the parent div
    const editables = div.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable]');

    // The buttons Save and Delete
    const saveBtn = div.querySelector('button.button-save');
    const deleteBtn = div.querySelector('button.button-delete');

    // Add click listeners to buttons
    saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Saved: ' + divId);

      const contentOfEditableDivs = Array.from(editables).map((div) => div.innerText);

      console.log('Values of divs:', contentOfEditableDivs);
    });
    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Deleted: ' + divId);

      const contentOfEditableDivs = Array.from(editables).map((div) => div.innerText);

      console.log('Values of divs:', contentOfEditableDivs);
    });
  });
```

```html
<div id="1" class="div-editable">
<div contenteditable>aaa</div>
<div contenteditable>bbb</div>
<div contenteditable>ccc</div>

<button class="button-save">SAVE</button>
<button class="button-delete">DELETE</button>
</div>

<div id="2" class="div-editable">
<div contenteditable>ddd</div>
<div contenteditable>eee</div>
<div contenteditable>fff</div>

<button class="button-save">SAVE</button>
<button class="button-delete">DELETE</button>
</div>

<div id="3" class="div-editable">
<div contenteditable>ggg</div>
<div contenteditable>hhh</div>
<div contenteditable>iii</div>

<button class="button-save">SAVE</button>
<button class="button-delete">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

EDIT 1: Added code snippet

EDIT 2: Simplified explanation

Answer (score 3):

You can send `this` keyword in the argument of click's event handler and then access the parent div's id.

So your HTML would look something like:

```
// rest of the code here
<button onClick="a(this, 'save')">SAVE</button>
<button onClick="a(this, 'delete')">DELETE</button>
// rest of the code here
```

And your JS code would change to:

```
function a(elem, value) {
  console.log(elem.parentNode.id);
}
```

More details on the following link:
[how i get parent id by onclick Child in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213858/how-i-get-parent-id-by-onclick-child-in-js/42214034)

Comment: Thanks, but how to retrieve the content of each of the three contenteditable divs inside the "parent" div?

Comment: They could be three or four.

Comment: You can then use `elem.parentNode.children` to access the children of the "parent" div. So if you need to get the value of 1st contenteditable div you can do something like `elem.parentNode.children.item(0).innerHTML`.

Comment: Or ```elem.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML``` (for the 1st contenteditable div).